# Lost connection to MySQL server during query In codeigniter query ,Live site

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm getting the following error on my live site.
"Error Number: 2013
Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

It was working fine before a day but now there is large amount of data, it might be problem.

I tried almost answers related to the error.

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Log output please :)

Comment: I tried to increase packet max limit but as its live site I couldn't complete it.  Other was to change the mysql version but that was also not possible for me . @AnatPort

Comment: Tried increating the cache size and memory limit?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use index in mysql database. It is very usefull when large amount of data in database. I have a same problem in live and it was solved by indexing.

Comment: Did you mean to say pagination?

Comment: No, Index functionality of database. Just check this link and follow the steps. It will helpful for your problem. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/three-easy-ways-to-optimize-your-mysql-queries/

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/three-easy-ways-to-optimize-your-mysql-queries/